# What plane is this, appearing in the movie Rampage?

Tags: aircraft-identification

The plane's registration number is barely visible. Unfortunately it's the best quality I could find.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [Boeing C-17 Globemaster III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_C-17_Globemaster_III). The tail markings appear to be those of the [437th Airlift Wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/437th_Airlift_Wing), US Air Force (thanks to [TomMcW](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/8730/tommcw) for the unit identification).

To answer the question yourself, note that you can see the US flag on the vertical stabilizer and the word "Force" behind the cockpit window. Wikipedia has a [list of planes flown by the US Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Air_Force#Aircraft_inventory) and, although the list is quite long, it is categorized by mission, which cuts down the options quite a lot – the plane obviously isn't a fighter, for example, and, conveniently, "cargo" is early in the alphabet so close to the top of the list.

The serial number 2300 (or 7300?) painted on the nose doesn't correspond to an actual [USAF C-17](https://www.planespotters.net/production-list/Boeing/C-17-Globemaster-III); it was probably temporarily renumbered while filming.

Comment: Though I'm slightly confused that the serial number on the nose (2300 or 7300) doesn't seem to match anything on [this list](https://www.planespotters.net/production-list/Boeing/C-17-Globemaster-III).

Comment: I think the number is "fake", as in "put explicitly for the movie and then removed"

Comment: If i were you id search for something like "military aircraft with four engines" in Google images and Google and move from there

Comment: @AliErdem That is surprisingly effective, given the number of different four-engined military planes there are. Or maybe Google is pushing C-17s up the list because I've done several searches related to them in the last few hours!

Comment: ...The "fake number" assumes that they used a real airplane for the shot, instead of a 3D model of some sort.

Comment: It appears to have the tail band from the 437th Airlift Wing out of Charleston.

Comment: Thanks, @TomMcW! I tried half-heartedly to identify that but there are enough units flying C-17s that I gave up.

Comment: @AliErdem I don't see how that is a useful comment

Comment: @Federico I think it's fine. My answer gives a way of identifying the plane; Ali gives a simpler way.